# Recommendation to choose API development open source Language, Framework and Database

Tags: mqtt, web-services, open-source, rest-api

I'm working in a IoT project and my role is to provide APIs to allow devices to communicate with server/database.
I have decided to use MySql for relational data like user details etc.. and MongoDb for other data like device data (Multi tenant data), and PHP Laravel framework for API development.

I just want to know if this is good combination of Language, Framework and Databases? if not then what is the good combination of Language, Framework and Database, as per my requirement.

As of now devices are limited but in future it may goes into thousands and can send data frequently (Once in a minute or once in 5 seconds). Most of the devices will be running on low power and memory, ex., Temperature, Humidity, Heart Beats sensors. Same time APIs will be used for web portal as well. End of the day Rest APIs will get used by Devices, WebPortal, MobileApp.

1. Is it good to use MongoDb+MySql over other databases like PostgresSQL? or any other suggestions.
2. Is it good to use two different platforms for API development, one for devices (MQTT+Mosquitto) and another for web portal and mobile app (Laravel). Or any suggestion to make this system better.
3. What programming language would you suggest in open source?

Comment: How many planned devices? What availability do you need? What reliability? How much data is communicated? You didn't really give any good requirements for picking either of those.

Comment: What are the IoT devices being used on the edge to collect the data which is then transferred to some data collection and storage facility? Most IoT devices are low powered, small micro-controller type devices with significant constraints on available memory and software functionality, e.g. no operating system. Typically these small devices sample some phenomena and report the measurements using a messaging protocol (CoAP, MQTT, AMQP) through a broker (RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ) where an observer then processes the data and stores it.

Comment: @RechardChambers As of now devices are limited but in future it may goes into thousands and can send data frequently (Once in a minute or once in 5 seconds). Most of  the devices will be running on low power and memory, ex., Temperature, Humidity, Heart Beats sensors. Same time Rest APIs will be used for web portal as well. End of the day Rest APIs will get used by Devices, WebPortal, MobileApp.

Comment: Standard REST over HTTP may not be appropriate for IoT edge devices to send their data. You really should update your posted question with additional details. You have described your technology approach but not really the business, problem domain requirements.

Comment: You might find this series of articles from Adafruit on transports https://learn.adafruit.com/alltheiot-transports of interest as it talks about various technologies and approaches.

Comment: Without a lot more constraints these questions are largely opinion based. Choices such as these come with a lots of pros and cons that need to be weighed up against all constraints - technical, budget, experience, business fit, timeframes, team size, etc., etc. Evaluating the options is a process, not a Q&A exercise.

Comment: Someone voted to close this as "primarilly opinion based" - and it is. i would say "stick with what you know". Personally, I don't see much point of 2 different databases, especially one SQL and one NoSql. If you know MySql then why not stick with that? Or Sqlite? Beware of database privileges; generally, I do not like anyone access my database remotely - I provide a RESTful HTTP CRUD API to the database server to interface with an application there that is the only thing allowed to access the database.

Comment: Nothing wrong with PHP; it runs over 90% of the world's server-side code. OTOH, if you don't know it yet, and think that  you might want to learn client side (browser) codding in future, then learn Node.Js for the server for this project, so that you don't need to learn a totally new language when you come to code for the browser.

Comment: A properly phrased question (totally avoiding words like "best") might be well received on  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (if you are for libraries or frameworks) or on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ if you ask about planning an architecture. As it stands, this question would be closed on both of those sites. Good luck - I hope that you get your answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a RESTlike Environment, you can setup:
PHP CodeIgniter + MariaDB
But you need to reconsider your requirements. Using REST over HTTP may require the use of intermediate techniques and a webservice based implementation.
If you are planning a real-time application, it would be better to use a telemetry messaging protocol, as MQTT.

In our IoT Lab we're implementing this configuration for a real-time solution:

- Fedora 26 Server
- Mosquitto MQTT Broker
- MongoDB
- Izmailoff's MQTT-Mongo (https://github.com/izmailoff/mqtt-mongo)

The IOT devices are "Adafruit Feather Huzzah" ESP8266, using arduino PubSubClient.h

The Mosquitto MQTT Broker has not (by now) any security configuration, and every port of MongoDB and MQTT is set by default.

Should work out of the box by setting up the data collections and documents on "application.conf" on Izmailoff's GitHub.

Comment: What are the edge IoT devices you are using and how are they configured?
Could you update your posted answer with additional details about the overall solution in addition to the back office or server repository side?

Comment: @CarlosMorenoSalazar I have updated my question for better understanding. Can you please clear if hybrid database is good to use in this system or should I go for any other database? Is it possible to use MQTT for web portal and mobile app as well? if yes then is it good to use MQTT in place of Rest API.